# Centering a <ul> <li> within two divs?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

Doesn't seem to be working in the latest version of Chrome but here's my code.

HTML

```
<div id="whole">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
            <center><a href="http://www.starworldhair.com"><img src="/images/starworldhair_logo.png" alt="Star World Hair Logo" width="350" /></a>

            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="topMenuContainer">
        <ul id="topNav">
            <li class='nav_whatsnew'><a href="http://www.starworldhair.com">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav_whatsnew"><a href="/our-products/">Our Products</a>

            </li>
            <li class="remihair"><a href="/brazilian-hair/">Brazilian</a> 
                <!-- <ul><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=35'>ALEXANDER</a></li><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=48'>RARE</a></li><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=49'>BARE & NATURAL</a></li><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=5'>GODDESS</a></li><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=4'>GODDESS SELECT</a></li><li class='text'><a href='/Catalog/catproduct/details?brandid=13'>GODDESS BUMP</a></li>

 </ul> -->
            </li>
            <li class="weaves"><a href="/indian-hair/">Indian</a>

            </li>
            <li class="wigs"><a href="/peruvian-hair/">Peruvian</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="allbrands"><a href="/chinese-yaki-hair/">Chinese Yaki</a>

            </li>
            <li class='nav_whatsnew'><a href="/about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li class='nav_whatsnew'><a href="/contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's all within the `<div id="whole">` code.

The CSS is:

```
 #topMenuContainer {
     /*position: absolute;*/
     /*top: 152px;*/
     /*left: 330px;*/
     /*text-align: center;*/
     /*width: 1005px;*/
     /*height: 250px;*/
     border: 0px dotted rgb(255, 0, 0);
     display:block;
     z-index:200;
     /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px #ccc;*/
 }
 #topNav {
     /*list-style: none;*/
     /*padding: 0px;*/
     /*margin: 0;*/
     /*float: left;*/
     width: 100%;
     height:30px;
     margin-bottom: -30px;
     /*background: transparent;*/
 }
 #topNav li {
     float: left;
     display:block;
     height:28px;
     margin: 0;
     border:0px #FF0000 solid;
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
     position: relative;
     /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
     list-style:none;
     margin-left: 5px;
     margin-right: 5px;
 }
 #topNav li a {
     /*padding: 0px 0px;*/
     height:30px;
     width:100%;
     /*line-height:100%;*/
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     /*text-indent: -3000px;*/
 }
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h3Xc3/).

If you want to see the website, it is at http://starworldhair.com/.  Trying to center the top menu with the logo.

Comment: What's all the commented-out material for? Also `<center>` is long-deprecated (citation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), please use a relevant HTML element (usually a `<div>`) and then use CSS to centre that element, `width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` usually does the trick).

Comment: I strongly suggest a complete review of this "page".   Why are images that are 3264x2448 being used if you're just going to shrink them down to 228px wide??   Try WEB OPTIMIZING the images on the site, and you'll see much better performance.   As mentioned above... `<center>` tag??  Really?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the criticism.  I'll center the logo div when I get the chance.  The site actually runs pretty smoothily but I'll optimize the images as well.  Thanks for the tips. kei's answer below was spot on.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Didn't work.  I used `text-align:center;`
@Charlie74 - The images you are referring to are 330px wide.  Biggest image I have is the background image which is scaled to cover a widescreen monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
#topNav { text-align:center }
#topNav li { float:none; display:inline-block }
```

Comment: Spot on! Used firebug to edit the CSS and then made the final changes on the actual server.  Worked like a charm and the ONLY one to directly answer the question.